# How can I load data files in a Jython module?

Tags: java, python, jython

I have some Jython modules that I'm trying to make work from within a JAR.  Everything is set up fine except that some modules expect to open files from the filesystem that are located in the same directory as the Python script itself.  This doesn't work anymore because those files are now bundled into the JAR.

Basically I want to know if there's an equivalent of Class.getResourceAsStream() that I can use from within the Python code to load these data files.  I tried to use `'__pyclasspath__/path/to/module/data.txt'` but it didn't exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In java `Class.getResourceAsStream()` uses java's class loading system to find a resource. Python's class loading mechanism is intended to provide some similar capabilities. Most of it is described [here](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#import) and in [PEP 302](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/).

A quick summary of this:

- when a python module is loaded, it's loader should set the `__loader__` attribute
- a loader should support [additional methods](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/#optional-extensions-to-the-importer-protocol) to get data from the same source

The default `zipimporter`, which is used when python classes are loaded from zip or jarfiles, luckily supports this methods. So if you know a data file is located in the same jar as a python module, you could use it's loader to load it:

```
import some_module
data = some_module.__loader__.get_data("path/in/archive/file.txt")
```

Comment: PEP 302 seems like exactly what I need, except that the importer seems to be a ClasspathPyImporter, not a zipimporter.  ClasspathPyImporter doesn't define get_data().

Also it would be nice to get the resource as a stream, not a giant string, but that doesn't matter too much.

Comment: Yes, you're right, seems modules loaded from the classpath are not loaded using a zipimporter, that's only used to load modules from zip/jars found in `sys.path` or JYTHONPATH, and that's what I tried...

Comment: That seems reasonable, as there's no guarantee that something in the CLASSPATH is actually in a JAR.  So I guess I should make a feature request to Jython for get_data in ClasspathPyImporter?

Comment: Done: http://bugs.jython.org/issue2058.  I'll keep the bounty up for a few days in case anyone has more insight, but I suspect this is the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm just missing the point, but can't you use getResourceAsStream() on a Java class?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, however I am not certain my circumstances were exactly the same.  I did not see the exception concerning the absence of `get_data` until I pushed my .jar to the web and tried to WebStart it, (WebStarting locally and starting my jar with `java -jar` worked fine).

Anyway, this is how I solved my problem:

```
import SomeClass
url = SomeClass.getClassLoader().findResource('path/to/resource.txt')
inputStream = url.openStream()
# ...
```

`SomeClass` is a Java class in my .jar file.  It happens to be the Java class that I use to start the Jython interpreter, so I know it will always be there.

Comment: Yeah I could do that but I'd also like the Python code to run with CPython, not just Jython.